# How can I root my Samsung Dart (SGH-T499)?

Tags: rooting, 2.2-froyo, samsung

I've seen several sites using SuperOneClick, but can't seem to find a legitimate download link to it. (The original site, [shortfuse.org](http://shortfuse.org) was down).

I then saw TowelRoot, but it tripped Norton, saying it was a Trojan.

I also looked at iRoot, which also tried to trick me into downloading a virus.

I thought the gurus here might have some advice (or even just a SuperOneClick executable) to help me out.

How do I root my device?

Thanks!

evamvid

PS I already looked at the one-root-question-per-device thread -- my device wasn't there.

PPS Possible relevant information -- It is speculated that this phone is a rebranding of the Galaxy Mini for T-Mobile, however it has capacitative buttons instead of the galaxy mini's tactile buttons. (I don't know if this helps)

PPPS [The original SuperOneClick thread on XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=8532790)

PPPPS I also checked KingoApp -- no dice